# Python Swift Client Object count mismatch with the actutal objects in cloud

Tags: python-3.x, cloud, openstack, openstack-swift, hp-cloud-services

I am using following command to list all the objects in the container and dumping into the log file.

```
swift -A url -U username -K password list container_name> log.txt
```

I have checked the number of lines in the output log file and it showing the  count  **1076857** . But when I have checked the cloud manually and found the  the count which is showing **1081756**. What might be the reason for this mismatch? Is the above command excludes the empty folder?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large files (greater than 5GB) are stored on Swift partially(?) which are called segments.

**For example:**
Let's assume we have a file with size **13 GB** and name **log.txt**.
We want to upload it to container **container1**.

This was the scenario, and **Swift does the following**:

1. Swift takes this file and divides into segments which are:

   ```
    log.txt_segment1 ---> size 5GB   
    log.txt_segment2 ---> size 5GB   
    log.txt_segment3 ---> size 3GB
   ```
2. Swift creates an object with name `log.txt` in `container1` with **size 0MB**. Actually this one is not a real object, it is only the alias name.
3. Then Swift creates another container with name `container1_segments` which stores the real object (segmented object) of `container1`.
4. Then Swift uploads the segments of the log.txt to `container1_segments`.

**So, what do we have now?**
    - we have ***2*** containers [`container1`, `container1_segments`]
    - we have ***4*** objects [`log.txt`, `log.txt_segment1`, `log.txt_segment2`, `log.txt_segment3`]

**Theoretically**:
We should have **1 container and 1 object**, but instead we have **2 containers and 4 objects**; maybe this causes the object count mismatch for your Swift.